# mongoid, creating references with roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, entity-relationship, mongoid

I am quite new to mongoDB and I'm just using it for a new rails project I'm working on.
What I wanted to do now is, having an (embedded) document reference another collection, but with different roles.

Somehow this doesn't seem to work. I know, that I can't define a relation from an external collection to my embedded one. So in my case, I cannot acces the Locations from my User and I'm fine with that. Still, I need to define the `referenced_in :location` part, because otherwise I get an error message `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` when I try to add a new Location to the Place.

So that's just the preface. My actual *problem* is, that these roles thing doesn't seem to work. When I create a new Location like that in a Place `locations.create(:user_a => some_user)`, then also `user_b` is set to that user.

Is there any way to make this working? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :locations
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :place, :inverse_of => :locations
  references_one :user_a, :class_name => "User" #, :stored_as => :array
  references_one :user_b, :class_name => "User" #, :stored_as => :array
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :location, :inverse_of => :dropper
  referenced_in :location, :inverse_of => :picker
end
```

Comment: which mongoid version you use ?

Comment: sry, completely forgot: mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20 on rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to disambiguate the two location associations (because the reference is stored on the referenced_in side):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :location_a, :inverse_of => :user_a, :class_name => "Location"
  referenced_in :location_b, :inverse_of => :user_b, :class_name => "Location"
end
```

I can't help feeling that there may be a better way to do this though...

Is this a better approach?

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :place, :inverse_of => :locations
  referenced_in :user_a, :class_name => "User"
  referenced_in :user_b, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

Comment: Well, the first one didn't work. But the second one seems to work obviously. I would have thought you always need to define the references_xyz part and this referenced_in is rather an optional "add-on" if you want the association to be navigable via both sites. But all my tests I defined so far are passing now. So thanks :)